# Ubuntu 14.04: All commands: "GLIBC_2.* not found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libc

So I stupidly ran a yum install command under root which had a load of dependencies which probably overwrite a lot of modules even up to the libc level.

I am running a 64 bit linux Ubuntu 14.04 box and should have used apt-get instead.

Every command I run now (bar some like 'cd') gives me as shown below...

Is there anyway I can reinstall libc on this box. I am currently accessing the box by a livecd and chrooting into the mounted disk.

Thanks for your help. Will.

```
root@ubuntu:/# ll
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3)

root@ubuntu:/# less
less: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5)
less: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5)
less: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5)
less: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5)

root@ubuntu:/# ls
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1)
ls: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3)
```